# div borders do not respect float while div content does

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have a div A which should be aligned accordingly to "float:left" rule of another div B positioned before it

the contents of this div A are being aligned correctly, but the borders and background not, they do not respect the "float:left" rule of the other div B and just go below it

see image
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKs3ENJmLAtMDVUY3ZhTFZQYWM/edit?usp=sharing

I notice that if I add a "display:table" to the style of my div A this issue is being solved, but then I have another one, which seems to be cause by the "display:table" rule:
the borders and background of my div are no more extended to the end of the page on the right, they just go around the content of the div

see image
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKs3ENJmLAtTHVZVnNPSm9FREE/edit?usp=sharing

given that this is a **responsive** website and I cannot use fixed width parameters for the elements, is there any css trick to solve the issue?

thank you!

Comment: _“the contents of this div A are being aligned correctly, but the borders and background not, they do not respect the "float:left" rule of the other div B and just go below it”_ – that is exactly the specified effect of float; so just _your understanding_ of what it does is wrong. To fix it to get what you _want_, research “containing floats”.

Answer (score 1):

In the 4+ years since this question was asked, Flexbox has become much more widely supported.

Using `display: flex;` on div A should work: https://codepen.io/davidding/pen/KxeWEP

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `display: inline-block` or you can set `margin-left` on the element, which will equal the width of the element above it, so it moves away from underneath it.

Comment: thank you, `display: inline-block` have a an effect very similar to `display: table`, and cause the borders and background of my div are no more extended to the end of the page on the right, they just go around the content of the div, while `margin-left` solve the issue but it's a great solution because this is a responsive website and so I'd need to add mediaqueries to change this rule depending on the screen size